# Short-circuit multiple expressions in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to run the following code within a function:

```
check_prob = function(probs){
    is.numeric(probs) &
    length(probs) > 1 &
    sum(probs) == 1
}
```

While this returns TRUE for appropriate test values, it returns an error for other inputs which would be expected to return FALSE. For example, 
    check_prob(letters)
returns the following error: Error in sum(probs) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

From playing around with the code, it appears the error stems from the last line of the function in finding the sum of the vector. Could someone clarify what's wrong with the logic in the code and other recommendations instead? Thank you!

Comment: Use `&&` rather than `&`. The double ampersand version is the short-circuit version.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use long-form, which are not vectorized and used for short-circuiting in R:

```
check_prob = function(probs){
  is.numeric(probs) &&
    length(probs) > 1 &&
    sum(probs) == 1
}
> check_prob(letters)
[1] FALSE
> check_prob(c(0.2, 0.4, 0.4))
[1] TRUE
```